# How do I select the right size Wabi

Tags: bike-fit

I would like to buy a Wabi Classic but I'm not sure if 49cm or 52cm will be a better fit. I have discussed this with support but I wanted to try a secondary source.

I have a list of measurements that I used in a fit calculator. I am just shy of 5'7" (5'6" and 3 quarters) with a 32" inseam. Here is a link to the results of using the calculator: https://imgur.com/kjjldMO

One major concern is the saddle to bar drop. Customer support reckons that it will be 11cm on the 49 and 8cm on the 52. 11cm seems like too much for me.

I just don't know how to make this decision. The ideal situation would be that I have both bikes in front of me to test. I don't feel that I'm close to this at all.

Thank you for any helpful input.

Comment: This isn’t a decision you should let strangers on the internet decide for you

Comment: If you can possibly try one in person, that can tell you a lot quickly.

Comment: Do you have another bike on which you feel comfortable?   Get a tape measure and take numbers from that frame, and compare them ?